# Template class with conditional typenames

Tags: c++, class, c++11, templates, class-template

I would like to have a template class (e.g. `float`/`double` type), but I am using *Nvidia CUDA* and *OptiX* and have multiple other types (e.g. `float2`, `double2`, `float3`,...) that depend on the chosen template type.

Something like this:

```
#include <optixu/optixu_vector_types.h>
#include <type_traits>

template <class T>
class MyClass 
{
   MyClass()
   {
      if (std::is_same<T, float>::value) 
      {
         typedef optix::float2 T2;
      }
      else if (std::is_same<T, double>::value)
      {
         typedef optix::double2 T2;
      }

      T2 my_T2_variable;
   }

   void SomeFunction() 
   { 
      T2 another_T2_variable; 
   };
};
```

My solution for now is to have multiple template arguments `MyClass<T,T2,T3> my_object;`, but this seems to have too much overhead and clutter. Is there a way to achieve the same with a single template argument as desired above?

Comment: what about C++20 concepts? https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constraints

Comment: I'd like to stick to C++11, if a solution exists.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Typically you'd do this by creating a trait type whose specializations define the additional types.  For example:

```
// Base template is undefined.
template <typename T>
struct optix_traits;

template <>
struct optix_traits<float> {
    using dim2 = optix::float2;
    // etc
};

template <>
struct optix_traits<double> {
    using dim2 = optix::double2;
    // etc
};
```

Then you can alias from these types to a name in your type, if desired:

```
template <typename T>
class MyClass {
public:
    using T2 = typename optix_traits<T>::dim2;
};
```

Comment: That worked. Thanks. On a minor note: I just noticed that I have private member functions that return `T2`/`T3` and it throws an error about the unkown (return) type `T2`? E.g. `T2 MyClass<T>::Foo(){return my_T2_variable;}` Can this be resolved somehow? Or shall I post a new question?

Comment: @SemtexB An out-of-class member function definition is not "in scope" until after it knows what type the member belongs to. When it sees `T2` there it doesn't know what `T2` is because it doesn't know the method is in `MyClass<T>` yet. Spell it all out: `template <typename T> typename MyClass<T>::T2 MyClass<T>::Foo() { ... }` Since C++11 you can also use `auto` to move the return type, like this: `template <typename T> auto MyClass<T>::Foo() -> T2 { ... }`. Since the return type appears after `MyClass<T>::` in that case, it knows to look in `MyClass<T>` for it.

Comment: Perfect, that worked. Thanks for the fast reply. I tried `template <typename T> MyClass::T2 MyClass<T>::Foo() { ... }`, but forgot the `typename` keyword and template argument...doh!

Comment: Summary: whereas all templates are meta-functions, type traits are the specific idiom we use when we want to define them more-or-less by enumerating all the possibilities, and where the outputs of the function(s) are a bunch of "facts" about the type (or you can call them properties or *traits* of the type). So, a simple mapping from a list of types to a list of other types pretty much *is* a type trait whether you think to name it that or not.

Answer (score 15):

You can use [`std::conditional`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/conditional), from `<type_traits>`.

If you want the `T2` be `optix::float2` when `T == float` and otherwise `optix::double2`, use [`std::conditional`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/conditional). This  is availble since [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11) and will resolve the type `T2` at compile time.

```
#include <type_traits>  // std::conditional, std::is_same

template <class T>
class MyClass
{
    using T2 = typename std::conditional<std::is_same<T, float>::value,
                                          optix::float2, optix::double2>::type;
    T2 my_T2_variable;

    // ... other code
};
```

**([See demo](https://godbolt.org/z/M1M0tq))**

---

As *@HikmatFarhat* pointed out, `std::conditional` will not catch the user mistakes.
It checks only the first condition, and for the `false` case gives the type `optix::double2`.

Another option is series of SFINAE ed functions, and [`decltype`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/decltype) to those for the `T2` as follows:

```
#include <type_traits>  // std::is_same, std::enable_if

template <class T> // uses if T == float and return `optix::float2`
auto typeReturn() -> typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<float, T>::value, optix::float2>::type { return {}; }

template <class T> // uses if T == double and return `optix::double2`
auto typeReturn() -> typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<double, T>::value, optix::double2>::type { return {}; }

template <class T>
class MyClass
{
    using T2 = decltype(typeReturn<T>()); // chooses the right function!

    T2 my_T2_variable;

    // ... other codes
};
```

**([See demo](https://godbolt.org/z/UfTOdx))**

Comment: yes but if he makes a mistake std::conditional will not catch it. For example calling it with std::string it defaults to optix::double2. Whereas the type_trait solution will give an error.

Comment: @HikmatFarhat You are right. Added another option, which is similar to the type_trait  solutions and should cover the issue.

Answer (score 6):

Implement a meta-function using template specialization that maps standard C++ types to OptiX types with the desired "rank":

```cpp
template <typename T, std::size_t N> struct optix_type;

template <> struct optix_type<float, 2> { using type = optix::float2; };
template <> struct optix_type<float, 3> { using type = optix::float3; };
template <> struct optix_type<double, 2> { using type = optix::double2; };
// ...

template <typename T, std::size_t N>
using optix_type_t = typename optix_type<T, N>::type;
```

You can then use this within your class(es) to easily get the right types:

```cpp
template <class T>
class MyClass {
  using T2 = optix_type_t<T, 2>;
  MyClass() {
    T2 my_T2_variable;
    optix_type_t<T, 3> my_T3_variable;
  }
  void SomeFunction() { T2 another_T2_variable; };
};
```